# ValueError: could not broadcast input array when assigning values to numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm pretty new with python and numpy in general so I don't exactly know what's going on. I have a lot of data stored in variable `X` where `X.shape = (N,1)`.

What I have looks like this:

```
X = np.genfromtxt("data.txt",delimiter=',');
# Running X.shape gives me (45000L,1L)

Yhat = np.zeros((X.size,25))
# Running Yhat.shape gives me (45000L,25L)

learner = [None] * 25

for i in range(0,25):
    learner[i] = treeRegress(X,dY)
    Yhat[:,i] = learner[i].predict(X)
    dY = dY * Yhat[:,i] * i
```

So basically, `dY` will change for each iteration of the loop. For each index of `learner` we will have a new result. My `predict` function then predicts a value for each value within `X` and then assigns each value to `Yhat` which puts this predicted value in a row with the column value of `i`.

Currently, this gives me an error:

```
    Yhat[:,i] = learner[i].predict(X)

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (45000,1) into shape (45000)
```

Doing `learner[i].predict(X).shape` returns `(45000,1)` and doing `Yhat[:,i].shape` returns `(45000,)`. So I understand why I can't do this. Unfortunately, if I use:

```
learner[i] = treeRegress(X,dY)
Yhat[:,i] = np.ravel(learner[i].predict(X))
```

This actually uses all of my memory and crashes my computer, so I can't exactly do that.

Also, the reason I need to have it stored in a column is because eventually I want to compute the sum in intervals like so:

```
for i in [1,5,10,25]:
    ysum = sum(Yhat[:,0:i])
    print ysum
```

So essentially I want to be able to iterate through certain intervals of columns. So, what am I doing wrong? Or is there some other way I need to structure these arrays? How should I be assigning the data into the column I want without everything around me crashing and burning?

Comment: Does this work with a smaller `X`?  What happens if, before the loop you do `Yhat += 1`?  That's a memory test.

Comment: I forbode that the problem is in the complexity of your predict method rather than data structure.